# Cannot see why dataset is disabled

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am getting this error message:

> [Firedac][Comp][DS]-213. Record editing for dataset [quUpdate] is disabled.

I can't see where or why it's disabled. I have checked the properties of the `TFDQuery` and the `DataSource`, but can't see anything out of the blue.

The only code I have to do with `quUpdate` is:

```pascal
quUpdate.SQL.text := 'select * from clients where ''' + tel +
  ''' IN (companytel,companytel_other)';
quUpdate.open;

clientid := quUpdate.fieldbyname('clientid').AsString;
```

All I want to do is pull through the data (which it does) and then update the information via `TDBEdit` using `.Edit` and `.Post`. Done this lots of times with no issue. I've tried adding `quUpdate.Edit` after the `quUpdate.Open` above, as well as trying a different SQL.

What have I missed?

Using Delphi 10.4

Comment: Which database?

Comment: It's sql server

Comment: (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDUpdateOptions.EnableUpdate)

Comment: That's not an update and does not try to write to the database (although why you have a `SELECT in your update query is really confusing, because it doesn't belong there - an update query should be using an `INSERT INTO` statement instead, because it's an **update query**. Doing a `SELECT` does not attempt to modify data, so it can't cause the error you describe.

Comment: TFDConnection has EnableUpdate which the TFDQuery will inherit. It defaults to true but perhaps has been set to false for the connection your query is using.